# Need decimals in answer -- Python Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

```
def f(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    elif x > 1:
        z = ((x**(x-1))/(x-1))
        b = z + f(x-1)
    return b
```

How can I get a number with decimal points? I've tried using float, but this doesn't work either. For example, if i do f(4) i get 28, but i want something like 28.833. Any advice?

Comment: Can you post the code where you "tried using float"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python2, the result of `int/int` is truncated to an `int`

If that is the problem, it should be sufficient to call `f(4.0)` since then `x-1` etc will be floats and so force a floating point division

Alternatively you can put

```
from __future__ import division
```

as the first line of you module

```
>>> def f(x):
...     if x == 1:
...         return 1
...     elif x > 1:
...         z = ((x**(x-1))/(x-1))
...         b = z + f(x-1)
...     return b
... 
>>> f(4)
28
>>> f(4.0)
28.833333333333332
```

Comment: You could force floats by changing `1` to `1.0` in the formula. `z = ((x**(x-1.0))/(x-1.0))`

Answer (score 0):

typecast your int to float

e.g. `float(3)/2 = 1.5`